# How to get a Service to change focus to your background Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-service

Sorry to ask this one.

I have a Service BroadcastReceiver.onReceive() that listens for Bluetooth devices when they connect, and displays a dialog to prompt the user to accept if my app should use the device.

The problem is, of course, that when you're connecting the bluetooth device, you're typically in the Settings menu, not in my app. My Service will see the BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED intent and try to display an AlertDialog that naturally doesn't have an Activity window to do so with:

```
02-23 13:22:19.099: E/AndroidRuntime(25884): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
02-23 13:22:19.099: E/AndroidRuntime(25884):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:563)
02-23 13:22:19.099: E/AndroidRuntime(25884):    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:269)
02-23 13:22:19.099: E/AndroidRuntime(25884):    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
02-23 13:22:19.099: E/AndroidRuntime(25884):    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:281)
02-23 13:22:19.099: E/AndroidRuntime(25884):    at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:951)
```

Here my onRecevie just for the hell of it: (I clipped and edited it, there might be a mmissing '}' )

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if(action.equals(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED)) {
            final BluetoothDevice btdevice = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            if (btdevice != null) {
                serviceHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                            .setTitle("Bluetooth PAN detected")
                            .setMessage(
                                    "Do you want to connect to this device?\n" +
                                    "Name: " + btdevice.getName() + "\n" +
                                    "MAC: " + btdevice.getAddress())
                            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }}
                            ).setNegativeButton("No", null).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyone have a suggestion on how a Service can force focus to an Activity so the Dialog could be drawn? Or is there another method in Android for Services to prompt or force user input? (I can think of a dozen reasons why this would be needed)

Thanks!

Comment: Most likely you just want to call startActivity and launch an appropriate activity for your app.

Comment: Please review the answers below and if it has solved your problem then please do accept it. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply show a `Notification` via your `Service` to the user and when the user selects that `Notification`, you can simply start your Activity where you let the user perform the tasks related to `BlueTooth` connectivity.

Here is a nice tutorial for implementing `Notifications`: 
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidNotifications/article.html

I hope this helps.

Comment: You know what, you're right. I already use notifications to indicate when my service starts or restarts on its own. e.g. when the wifi IP changes. I'm going to handle this 2 fold. 1) Notification for when the Activity isn't active. 2) When the Activity resumes I'll display the dialog. Thanks for the advice. Sometimes you're too close and impatient to see the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a startActivity with an appropriate intent to start your activity or bring it to the front - the message would then be displayed by the activity in response to the intent. You can manipulate the flags on the intent to specify to switch to the current activity or create a new one for the purpose.